# Need list of id's of all the processes created by a python code in python

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing

I'm using multiprocessing and selenium in python when my code runs, it create lots of different subprocesses (Firefox webdriver and python). My objective is to get list of process-id of all active processes at the end which my code have started and kill them. How should I do this ? Any help ?

Comment: If your codes executes properly, Then all the sub-process will exit by itself. Thee is no need to kill it explicitly unless you are triggering some other sub-process from your program and it  runs continuously in back-end.

Comment: Yes, You're right. So I actually trigger selenium process which many times doesn't get closed by itself or just hangs. I just want a way which will insure that all the child processes are terminated once the program exit / in case of any exception.

Answer (score 0):

For every process you create with multiprocessing you can obtain the pid by doing this:

```
p.pid
```

Just save all the processes on a list and then when you need the pid just execute the previous instruction for every element on the list

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response but how should create variable common for all the processes ? I've global variables in my program but what I know is that all the process in multiprocessing pool creates it's own copy of global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use Python API, it's simple:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    print browser.binary.process.pid
```

You can kill the process id using kill -9 , or tskill etc